# React Native not connecting to Firebase Database

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I've been working with a React Native app that utilizes the Firebase Realtime database for several months now. Recently, the app refuses to connect to the database despite having made no changes to the code. When I try to run `database().ref("ref").on("value", ...)`, the function does not error but instead never resolves. Additionally, querying the `.info/connected` ref returns `false`.

Query function:

```js
import database from "@react-native-firebase/database";

database().ref(".info/connected").on("value", v => console.log("connected", v.val()));
database().ref(`/v2/teams/${teamID}`).on("value", v => console.log("team", v.val()));
```

Package.json dependencies:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "15.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "15.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "9.2.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/database": "7.5.5",
    "@react-native-firebase/functions": "15.3.0",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.2",
}
```

I tried creating a blank test project following the instructions [here](https://rnfirebase.io/), but that test project also failed to connect to my database. I also have a website which queries the same database which is perfectly fine, and there are no issues with database load or performance. I'm not receiving any errors of any kind so I'm somewhat lost as what to pursue.

Comment: Kind of -- I ended up taking a break from the project for two months, and after I came back the problem went away and hasn't come back since. Not sure what changed since I hadn't touched it at all and it just ended up working.